# Updating default contact on customer adds new record

Tags: acumatica

I have a method that either adds or updates a customer using the CustomerMaint graph.

My methods works apart from one strange thing that is happening.

After the customer is inserted.  If I go through the method to update the contact a second contact record is created on the contacts table.  If I then update again it behaves correctly and no new contact record is created and the default contact record is updated.

Here is my method

```
    private PX.Objects.AR.Customer UpdateContact(ContactRead rexContact, PX.Objects.AR.Customer m, bool insert = true)
    {

        PX.Objects.CR.Contact defContact = null;

        PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint>();

        graph.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearAll);

        //Add Customer and BAccount Records
        m.AcctCD = "V" + rexContact._id;
        m.AcctName = rexContact.system_search_key;
        m.Type = "CU";

        if (insert) {
            m = graph.CurrentCustomer.Insert(m);
            defContact = graph.DefContact.Current;
        }  
        else {
            defContact = PXSelect<PX.Objects.CR.Contact, Where<PX.Objects.CR.Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<PX.Objects.CR.Contact.contactID>>>>.Select(this, m.DefContactID);
        }

        //Update Default Contact Record
        defContact.ContactType = "AP";
        defContact.FullName = rexContact.system_search_key;

        if (rexContact._related.contact_emails != null)
        {
            if (rexContact._related.contact_emails.Length > 0) defContact.EMail = rexContact._related.contact_emails[0].email_address;
        }

        if (rexContact._related.contact_phones != null)
        {
            if (rexContact._related.contact_phones.Length > 0) defContact.Phone1 = rexContact._related.contact_phones[0].phone_number;
        }

        graph.DefContact.Update(defContact);

        //Change customer class to vendor
        m.CustomerClassID = "VENDOR";
        graph.CurrentCustomer.Update(m);

        graph.Actions.PressSave();

        return m;

    }
```

Comment: is your method executed twice?

Comment: In which method your function UpdateContact is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are inserting your customer on a view different than the primary view. Inserting something in `graph.CurrentCustomer` will not properly set the current record, which may result in unpredictable behaviour when you try to access `graph.DefContact.Current`. You should instead insert the contact into `graph.BAccount`, which is the primary view of the customer maintenance graph.

Also, when you're updating an existing customer's contact (instead of inserting new customer), you should still set `graph.BAccount.Current` value to a customer you retrieved using `Locate` or a `PXSelect`, and retrieve the default contact using `graph.DefContact.Select()` instead of doing a full `PXSelect`.

Comment: Thankyou that worked using BAccount instead of currentcustomer.

On updating the default contact I still had to get the contact using PXSelect and set graph.DefContact.Current to the resulting contact.  Setting just graph.BAccount.Current didn't load in the defcontact came up null.

Comment: Hmm... strange. I thought system would change the DefContact immediately when you change the current customer. Try following - will still be simpler: defContact = graph.DefContact.Select();